# How to identify language using ML.NET?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, fasttext, ml.net

Is it possible to identify language using ML.NET like fastText does it, but it is in python:
https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html

But I'd like to do it in SQLCLR function and in NET Core application.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want to do, especially related to SQLCLR, (you do know that SQLCLR is related to .NET assemblies in SQL Server).

Comment: Yes, I know what is SQLCLR and I developed them. It is only idea: create a SQLCLR function which can be called and identify text's language of table field. This table contains books descriptions. When this function is in db I can call it in any client applications

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server should be .NET Framework only, so I don't see a single .NET Core library being an option.

Also, while the ReadMe for the [main ML.NET repository](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning) does state:

> ML.NET also works on the .NET Framework 4.6.1 or later, but 4.7.2 or later is recommended.

Also, a white-paper on ML.NET stated that a portion of it is written in C++, and that could mean that one or more DLLs are mixed-mode (not pure MSIL) in which case that would not load into SQL Server under any circumstance (i.e. not even marked as `UNSAFE`). But you are certainly welcome to try loading the ML.NET libraries into SQL Server to see if it works. But even if it does, you likely have a lot of work ahead of you in terms of re-creating what they did with fastText.

You *might* be able to make use of this C# wrapper for fastText:

https://github.com/rafael-aero/fastText/tree/master/vs2015

You will still need the main fastText library, **fastText.dll**, as the wrapper code will call it. The wrapper code will need to be loaded as UNSAFE due to the calls to unmanaged code.

If you do try this and it does work, please let us know.

Comment: Thnx, I will try this way. But there is another question: now I am testing the WinForms +ML.NET app which can detect the language. But it used a model.zip file from disk. Is it possible to use prepared model not from file but from db or stream etc?

Comment: Btw, I have found yet another cross-platform wrapper https://github.com/olegtarasov/fastText